# QR code - where can I find (free) code to embed my own generator on a web page?

Tags: barcode, qr-code

couldn't find it exactly from earlier questions, but I am probably repeating an earlier question, so apologies upfront ;-)

I am looking for a simple code to embed a QR 2D code generator on a website I am building. I assume their should be some free open source code for that but I could only find paid software.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? would be mostly appreciated!

best regards,

Robbert

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/08/qr-code-generator-plugin-for-jquery.html

Or indeed, even easier, Google provide one

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html

SO you just need an IMG tag with the parameters set

[edit]

ie:  This is the QR code for this page:

https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451010/&choe=UTF-8
[image]

Comment: Google QR code gallery link is broken. Also, "Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated".

Comment: @zaf Yeah...looks like that URL to generate the qrcode will stop working in 2015... Google don't seem to provide a replacement

Answer (score 1):

ZXing will do it.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/